# SQLAlchemy + MySQL joins strange behaviour

Tags: python, mysql, sql, flask, sqlalchemy

Following [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34716613/raw-sql-to-sqlalchemy).

I have noticed that raw sql statement generated by ORM translates `.join` into unspecified SQL `JOIN`.

Running this generated statement in sql command line returns unexpected result, but adding `LEFT` to each join in statement makes result right.

As I know in MySQL `LEFT` is optional, so adding it explicitly makes no sense, so why the results are different?

Where is the mistake?

Comment: `left` is optional, but if left out the join is an `inner` (at least in sql-server, I assume mysql too). Obviously, an `inner join` may produce different results to a `left join`

Comment: What was the "expected" result?

Comment: @philipxy, the result which I get from the initial raw SQL query.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

LEFT JOIN and JOIN (aka INNER JOIN) are different operations.

LEFT JOIN returns what JOIN returns plus a row for every unmatched row in the left argument. The added row looks like the unmatched row extended by NULL for every column of the right argument.

JOIN calculates all possible combinations of a row from the left argument extended by a row of the right argument then keeps only rows that match the ON condition. CROSS JOIN is like JOIN ON 1=1.

(In MySQL a JOIN can have no ON, which means a CROSS JOIN.)